# Method for getting selected checkbox and calling an action in it

Tags: jquery, html

I want to loop through the table to get the selected checkbox value on click of a button .

```
<table border="1" style="border: #4F81BD" id="Education">
    <tr>
        <td class="names">S.No</td>
        <td class="names">Education</td>
        <td class="names" >Data Source</td>
        <td class="names" >District </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="names" >CSV Download</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trr1" >
        <td class="names">1.</td>
        <td class="names" >Literacy rate (>6 years)

        </td>
        <td class="names">Census of India</td>
        <td class="names">Literacy rate is the % of people > 6 years reported as literate as per census of India.</td>
        <td>
          <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="LiteracyRate"><br>
        </td>
        <td>
    </tr> 
</table>
<input type="button"  value="Download" onclick="getSelectedRecords('Education');" />
```

i m new in jquery can any one help in this. and i also need to call an action in loop in the function .

Comment: have you tried anything??

Comment: yes but It doesn't get called ..

Comment: you should share that code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('table input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
        console.log($(this).val());
    })

});
```

please try above code

Comment: it's better to wrap it with `$(document).ready(function(){ /* that code */ });` to make sure the binding happened after the element rendered correctly

Comment: can you please tell me how can i call this method on "onclick" of button

Answer (score 0):

Write this code inside `document-ready` .

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pspo2spw/1/):**

```
$('#btn_idOrclass').click(function(){
    $('table input[type=checkbox]:checked').filter(function(){
           return $(this).val();    
      });
});
```

Comment: it is not getting called .... i tried to show alert but still it is not getting called

Comment: did u check in fiddle ?

Comment: can you show me the entire HTML that contains button and the table structure ?

Comment: okay ...kindly upvote or accept it as answer if it fulfills your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You should give all of those checkobox from this table the same class or id i.e. `class="mycheckboxes"`
then after clicking your button you take only checked checkbox and get value from it. I mean something like this:

`$.find(".buttonclass").click(function() {
        var valueFromSelectedCheckbox = $.find("table").find(".mycheckboxes:checked").val();
    });`

and in valueFromSelectedCheckbox you have your value

Answer (score 0):

well i tried lots of example ,but this one helps me out in getting values of all selected checkboxes

```
     $(document).ready(function () {
         $('#Download').click(function () {

             debugger
             var trArray = jQuery('#Education').find('tbody').find('tr');
             if (trArray && trArray.length > 0) {

                 var categories = [];
                 var data = [];
                 alert('button clicked');
                 for (var i = 0; i < trArray.length; i++) {
                     var tdArray = jQuery(trArray[i]).find('td');
                     if (tdArray && tdArray.length > 0) {
                         if (jQuery(tdArray[4]).find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked') == true) {
                             //categories.push(jQuery(tdArray[1]).text());
                             var values = [];
                             for (var j = 0; j <1; j++) {
                                 var d = jQuery(tdArray[j]).text();
                                 var e = jQuery(tdArray[4]).find('input[type="checkbox"]').val();
                                 //values.push(parseFloat(d));
                             }
                             data.push({ name: jQuery(tdArray[0]).text(), data: values });
                             categories.push(e);

                         }
                     }
                 }
                 alert(categories);

             }
     });
     });
 </script>
```